# com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.] Android, Firebase, Google Auth

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I've been trying for 3 days but cant solve the problem. The application connects with Google, I can get the information of the user, but Firebase does not save. private fun

```
firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idtoken : String?) {

        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idtoken, null)
        println(credential)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                    user = auth.currentUser!!
                    Toast.makeText(this,"başarılı",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.

                    // ...
                    Toast.makeText(this,"olmadııııııııııı",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    updateUI(null)
                }


            }
    }
```

I can intent to other activity but when I go Toast shows "olmadııııııııııı". So I think the problem 
signinwithcredential. I also enableb the google sign-in method in firebase and entered my SHA-1 fingerprint.
What should I do ?
[I get this error on auth.signInWithCredential() ->if(task.isSuccessful)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSVYi.png)

Comment: If the task is not successful, there will be an exception in the Task object.  Use `task.exception`, and log it to find out what happened.

Comment: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.]

Sorry i dont know how i comment a pic.

Comment: you can edit your question and add a picture

Comment: Sounds like you didn't integrate Firebase into your app correctly.

Comment: But i did all the things on the Firebase Google Sign-in auth guide documents.